# Maximum recursion limit - property values set back to NaN

Tags: matlab

I am having a go at matlab object orientated programming. I have a class with properties. The properties are computed if they are NaN otherwise the property is returned.

So I have this section:

```
properties 
 some_property = NaN;
end
```

and a property is computed like this:

```
function some_property = get_some_property(obj)

if(isnan(obj.some_property))

    % do some expensive computation
    obj.some_property = ...;

end

some_property = obj.some_property;
```

A get_some_property method can be used by another get_some_property method. The problem is that between method calls properties are set back to NaN. This causes the error:

Maximum recursion limit ...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is your class a reference type or value type? If reference then you will inherit from `handle`.

Comment: not sure what you are referring to. do you ask whether ny class derives from < handle?

Comment: Yes, see  sfstewman answer below if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your class is not derived from `handle`, so it's passed around as a value.  This means that when you call `get_some_property`, Matlab faithfully duplicates `obj`, giving a copy to the function `get_some_property` and keeping that separate from the copy of the code that called `get_some_property`.  So, when you change `some_property` in the function `get_some_property`, it changes the property on the value of `obj` in the function, but not the property of `obj` in the code that called it.

There are two solutions to your problem. The best solution (IMO) is to derive your class from `handle`.  Classes derived from `handle` are passed as references, so when you change the property on `obj`, it will change the property everywhere.

However, if you're unwilling to do this, then you can return `obj` from `get_some_property`:

```
function [some_property,obj] = get_some_property(obj)
```

And then call `get_some_property` in this way:

```
[property,obj] = get_some_property(obj);
```

This updates the value of `obj` in the calling namespace.  It's both awkward and clunky; I would derive your classes from `handle` unless there's a good reason to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. That solved one issue. The other one is a semantic error (stackoverflow) which is my fault.